# Change Accept-Language Header with javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My API uses the Accept-Language header to get it's current language which returns the json translated. Never mind that.

How can i change the header with angularJS/Javasctipt. I tried this:

```
  $http.defaults.headers.post["Accept-Language"] = "bs-Latn-BA";
```

but it doesn't seem to work, are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default headers sent for every single request live in the `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common` object.

You can change or augment these headers using the `.config()` function for every request, like so:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
   .config(function($httpProvider) {
      $httpProvider.defaults.headers
        .common['Accept-Language'] = 'bs-Latn-BA';
});
```

We can also manipulate these defaults at run time using the defaults property of the `$http` object. For instance, to add a property for dynamic headers, we can set the header property like so:

```
$http.defaults
   .common['Accept-Language'] = "bs-Latn-BA";
```

Comment: Thanks, got it ^^ this way i can add any custom header?

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS you can set common headers by using $httpProvider. [Angularjs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$httpProvider)

Example:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

    app.config(["$httpProvider", function($httpProvider) {
        // set Accept-Language header on all requests to
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept-Language"] = "bs-Latn-BA";
    }]);
```